# Merge all .csv files in folder by a common field present in each file

Tags: python, csv

So, I have a directory with .csv files. For example:

**a.csv**

```
id,name
1,john
2,mary
3,alex
```

**b.csv**

```
id,birth
1,01.01.2001
2,05.06.1990
```

**c.csv**

```
id,death
2,01.02.2020
1,-
```

The result should be one dict where the key is id (int) and value is a dict of all the different values across the the files(dict of dicts). Something like this:

```
{
        1: {"id": 1, "name": "john", "birth": "01.01.2001", "death": -},
        2: {"id": 2, "name": "mary", "birth": "05.06.1990",
            "death": "01.02.2020"},
        3: {"id": 3, "name": "alex", "birth": None, "death": None},
}
```

So far I've tried to merge all files into one dataframe:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import pandas as pd

files = Path(r'path').rglob('*.csv')

# read in all the csv files
all_csvs = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in files]

# lump into one table
all_csvs = pd.concat(all_csvs, axis=1)
```

But as a result I get a dataframe where 'id' is repeated in three columns.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want `merge` and not `concat`. Since you need to merge *multiple* DataFrames, you can do:

```
import os
from functools import reduce

all_csvs = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in os.listdir() if file.endswith(".csv")]
df = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, how="outer", on="id"), all_csvs)

>>> df

   id  name       birth       death
0   1  john  01.01.2001         NaN
1   2  mary  05.06.1990  01.02.2020
2   3  alex         NaN         NaN

#for dictionary output replacing nan with None
my_dict = df.where(df.notnull(), None).set_index("id", drop=False).to_dict(orient="index")
>>> my_dict

{1: {'id': 1, 'name': 'john', 'birth': '01.01.2001', 'death': None},
 2: {'id': 2, 'name': 'mary', 'birth': '05.06.1990', 'death': '01.02.2020'},
 3: {'id': 3, 'name': 'alex', 'birth': None, 'death': None}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it without pandas if you're so inclined. First, create a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) that'll hold all your csv data. Let the default element of this dict be a dictionary representing a "default" person, i.e. with all keys having a value of `None`.

```
import collections

def default_person():
    return {'id': None, 'name': None, 'birth': None, 'death': None}
all_csvs = collections.defaultdict(default_person)
```

The keys in this dict will be the `id` field, and values will be the dict containing all the information you want.

Next, read each file using [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). `DictReader` reads each row of your csv file as a dictionary, with keys coming from the file's header. Then for each row in each file, update the values of the dictionary at the correct `id` in the `defaultdict` we just created:

```
import csv

files = Path(r'path').rglob('*.csv')

for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as f_in:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
        for row_dict in reader:
            p_id = row_dict['id'] = int(row_dict['id']) # Convert `id` to integer
            all_csvs[p_id].update(row_dict)
```

Now, `all_csvs` looks like so:

```
defaultdict(<function __main__.default_person()>,
            {
             1: {'id': 1, 'name': 'john', 'birth': '01.01.2001', 'death': '-'},
             2: {'id': 2, 'name': 'mary', 'birth': '05.06.1990', 'death': '01.02.2020'},
             3: {'id': 3, 'name': 'alex', 'birth': None, 'death': None}
            })
```